# How to remove \t from NSMutableAttributedString?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsattributedstring

I have NSMutableAttributedString whose string contains tabs. I want to remove it

Sample NSstring

```
Hello text
    •   Text1
    •   Text2
    •   Text3
```

I tried the below code but it doesn't work as expected.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *displayText;
NSCharacterSet *charSet = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet];
NSRange range           = [displayText.string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:charSet];

while (range.length != 0 && NSMaxRange(range) == displayText.length)
{
    [displayText replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:@""];
    range = [displayText.string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:charSet];
}

// Trim trailing whitespace and newlines.
range = [displayText.string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:charSet options:NSBackwardsSearch];
while (range.length != 0 && NSMaxRange(range) == displayText.length)
{
    [displayText replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:EMPTY_STRING];
    range = [displayText.string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:charSet options:NSBackwardsSearch];
}
```

The output I am getting is

```
Hellotext
•Text1
•Text2
•Text3
```

Actual output should be like

```
Hello text
 • Text1
 • Text2
 • Text3
```

Can someone help me out on this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `+whitespaceCharacterSet` includes spaces as well as tabs. If you only want to match tabs, create a custom set:

```
NSCharacterSet *charSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\t"];
```

Answer (score 2):

For using a charater set that only has `tab` character, u can use this:

```
NSMutableCharacterSet *charSet = [NSMutableCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet];
[charSet removeCharactersInString:@" "];
```